# Convert excel rows to pdf loop

Tags: excel, pdf

I wonder if you can help me modify this code ... it uses a dataset to look up against an indicator row to match field and complete a form for an indicator definition. This can be completed one or many times by modifying a column to `yes` or `no`.

It currently exports each indicator to a separate `PDF` - I would like the range of indicators selected combined as a single pdf - is this possible in the export? Possibly something like this to [union](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=197114) print ranges?

Or if possible to paste each output as image to empty worksheet then export as pdf?

```
Sub print_selected_rows(inputData As Range, outputData As Range)

Dim data_columns, data_rows, filter_column, i, j
Dim ThisFile As Variant

data_rows = getArrayRows(inputData)
data_columns = getArrayColumns(inputData)

For i = 1 To data_columns
If (inputData.Cells(1, i).Value = "Select for report") Then
    filter_column = i
    Exit For
End If
Next

Sheets("Output").Visible = True
Sheets("Output").Select

For i = 1 To data_rows
If ((inputData.Cells(i, filter_column).Value = "yes") Or (inputData.Cells  (i, filter_column).Value = "Yes") _
    Or (inputData.Cells(i, filter_column).Value = "Y") Or (inputData.Cells(i, filter_column).Value = "y")) Then
'copy row data to output sheet
    For j = 1 To data_columns
        outputData.Cells(j, 3).Value = inputData.Cells(i, j).Value
    Next

    ThisFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        "abc" & " " & _
        Range("selected_ID").Value, "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
    If VarType(ThisFile) = vbString Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
End If
Next

Sheets("Introduction").Visible = True
Sheets("Introduction").Select
Sheets("Output").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by copy and pasting as image to a new worksheet using the following code:

```
Sub print_selected_rows(inputData As Range, outputData As Range)

Dim data_columns, data_rows, filter_column, i, j, k
Dim ThisFile As Variant

k = 0

data_rows = getArrayRows(inputData)
data_columns = getArrayColumns(inputData)

For i = 1 To data_columns
If (inputData.Cells(1, i).Value = "Select for report") Then
    filter_column = i
    Exit For
End If
Next

Sheets("Output").Visible = True
Sheets("Output").Select

For i = 1 To data_rows
If ((inputData.Cells(i, filter_column).Value = "yes") Or (inputData.Cells (i, filter_column).Value = "Yes") _
    Or (inputData.Cells(i, filter_column).Value = "Y") Or (inputData.Cells(i, filter_column).Value = "y")) Then
'copy row data to output sheet
    For j = 1 To data_columns
        outputData.Cells(j, 3).Value = inputData.Cells(i, j).Value
     Next
      With ThisFile
        Sheets("Output").Range("A1:J55").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste _
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(k, 0)
        k = k + 56
      End With
End If
Next

Sheets("Introduction").Visible = True
Sheets("Introduction").Select
Sheets("Output").Visible = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = False

End Sub
```