# Excel images not exporting to PDF after copypicture

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

Have worked to copy a range of cells as picture to a seperate worksheet [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423307/convert-excel-rows-to-pdf-loop) The range of cells automatically populate based on self selection on another worksheet - so this effectively builds a series of images intended to be and indicator pack.

Have now written something to export to PDF - the print area uses the offset function depending on the number of indicators selected.

But the export to PDF runs but does not pick up the pictures - can you help?

```
Sub printPDFSave()

Dim rng As Range
Dim fPathFile As Variant

Set rng = [Destination]

fPathFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(filefilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
If fPathFile <> False Then
    rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fPathFile,  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,  OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you check if the Property `Print object` for the images is set? (Right click on image, "Format Picture", "Properties")

Comment: Yes Print object is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the below..we suppose that images are in sheet2

```
Option Explicit

Sub printPDFSave()

Dim rng As Range
Dim fPathFile As Variant
Dim sh As Shape
Dim ShRow As Long

For Each sh In Sheet2.Shapes
    ShRow = sh.BottomRightCell.Row
Nex

Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A1:K" & ShRow)

fPathFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(filefilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")

If fPathFile <> False Then
    rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fPathFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - but my range is dynamic, so its always in columns A:K but can be varied row lengths ... Thats why I had named the offset [Destination].

Comment: please check again ...i did it with the dynamic rows